# Magento - local controller is not working

Tags: magento, controller, overriding, local

I have a question regarding Magento's local directory.

I am trying to override a core controller - `Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php`.

So I copied IndexController.php to `/app/local/Mage/Contacts/controllers/`

but Magento is still using core file. I can confirm it because I see 404 page when I rename Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php to IndexController.php_.

Please advise me.

Thanks!

Comment: Have the same problem, solution -

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19814600/magento-copy-controller-to-local?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Copying a controller into the `app/code/local` path doesn't work unfortunately due to Magento's autoload architecture.  It does work with Blocks, Models and other objects, but not controllers.

There is a detailed walkthrough of how to override a controller on the [wiki](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/how_to_overload_a_controller).  And a [blog post](http://prattski.com/2010/06/24/magento-overriding-core-files-blocks-models-resources-controllers/) by @prattski

Try following those, then come back with any specific questions.

HTH, 
JD

Comment: For me it does not for with some blocks either (e.g. /local/Mage/GoogleAnalytics/Block/Ga.php). Would really like to know the algorithm Magento uses to determine when to use local directory instances and when not.

Comment: Your links are dead now. Thats why you should always add all relevant informations to your post.