# Magento copy controller to local

Tags: php, magento

When I copy some `core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/` files to `local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/` everything work's fine, but if I copy controller to `local/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers` - core controller still works and system don't see my local/ ... controller.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because controllers are loaded in a different way than other type classes. You don't do it by referencing to `Mage` class. To know how they are loaded lets look at a standard Magento router and its method `getControllerFileName()`:

```
// Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard
public function getControllerFileName($realModule, $controller)
{
    $parts = explode('_', $realModule);
    $realModule = implode('_', array_splice($parts, 0, 2));
    $file = Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', $realModule);
    if (count($parts)) {
        $file .= DS . implode(DS, $parts);
    }
    $file .= DS.uc_words($controller, DS).'Controller.php';
    return $file;
}
```

Then lets look at `Mage_Core_Model_Config::getModuleDir()` method (config class is referenced inside `Mage::getModuleDir()`):

```
public function getModuleDir($type, $moduleName)
{
    $codePool = (string)$this->getModuleConfig($moduleName)->codePool;
    $dir = $this->getOptions()->getCodeDir().DS.$codePool.DS.uc_words($moduleName, DS);

    (...)
}
```

As you can see, Magento get real module code pool in this case. That's why simple copy won't work. You have to rewrite controllers.

If you don't know how to properly rewrite a controller let me know in the comments. I will update this answer accordingly.

**EDIT**

To rewrite a controller you need to create a new module in local code pool (or use existing one). If you don't know how to create a module check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5594920/400437) SO topic. Lets assume that you want to make a rewrite of Magento Onepage checkout controller.

In config.xml of a module add this:

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <checkout>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <mynamespace_mymodule before="Mage_Checkout">MyNamespace_MyModule</mynamespace_mymodule>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </checkout>
    </routers>
</frontend>
<!-- rewrite of admin controllers are the same. instead of <frontend> use <admin> -->
```

Next, create a controller in your module in app/code/local/MyNamespace/MyModule/controllers. Name it the same as controller that is being rewritten. You must use the same folder structure as Magento use. In our case we create a `OnepageController.php` in controllers folder.

```
//you have to manually include the controller being rewritten, because Magento autoloader cannot automatically resolve it.
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Checkout') . DS . 'OnepageController.php';

class MyNamespace_MyModule_OnepageController extends Mage_Checkout_OnepageController
{
    //copy a method you want to rewrite, e.g.
    public function saveOrderAction()
    {
         //Method body
    }
}
```

And that's it! Note that you need to flush Magento cache after doing this. Admin controllers are very similar to rewrite. Just change a `<frontend>` to `<admin>` and you're good to go. Usually it's a good practice to place admin controllers to `Adminhtml` subfolder of `controllers` folder. So example config.xml would look like this:

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <mynamespace_mymodule before="Mage_Checkout">MyNamespace_MyModule_Adminhtml</mynamespace_mymodule>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Note that controller path has changed to `MyNamespace_MyModule_Adminhtml` but it does not contain `controllers`.

Magento will automatically look to controllers with the same relative path and controller name.

Comment: So how can I rewrite controller?

Comment: I need to add some functionality to `Mage_Adminhtml_Promo_CatalogController` -> `saveAction()`

Comment: @ventus nice answer.. please complete your answer.this will be helpful for everyone , please elaborate how to rewrite controller. thanks.

Comment: I have edited my answer and added info on how to rewrite a Magento controller.

Comment: Also you can use the Rewrite Controller feature from Magicento: http://magicento.com/#feature5